# How to add PhantomJSDriver command line arguments

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

How can I specify command line arguments for my Java [PhantomJSDriver](https://cdn.rawgit.com/detro/ghostdriver/master/binding/java/docs/javadoc/index.html)? For example, I want to set `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes` on the script that I run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add to phantomJS's default desired capabilities, like so:

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.cli.args", Collections.singletonList("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes"));

PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. nice spot, thanks! Copied from code I had. Fixed now.

Comment: Excellent thank you! My local tests were working fine but I guess someone has made a certificate change, I added "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes" and my tests are running again

Comment: While your code did not fix my specific problem, it at least helped me eliminate something as a possible cause, and yours is the only example of how to pass command-line options to phantomjs selenium webdriver.  I've been searching for hours and lucked upon this.