# Ruby & Selenium - how to pass arguments to browser?

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox

My search has only turned up answers for Java - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256617/how-can-i-tell-selenium-to-start-firefox-with-certain-commandline-options) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721486/how-to-add-phantomjsdriver-command-line-arguments)

The selenium gem doesn't include `addCommandLineOptions` as far as I can tell, but it does have `WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities`.

How do I use it to add arguments? I know you pass it as `desired_capabilities:` to the driver constructor, but in what format?

Unfortunately [the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Remote/Capabilities) has been especially useless

Answer (score 1):

You can set `--start-maximized`by following for Chrome. See [this post](http://www.testrisk.com/2016/08/using-chromeoptions-for-capybara.html) for more details.

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome_maximize do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome( 
    'chromeOptions' => {
      "args" => [ "--start-maximized", "--otherthings" ]
    } 
  )

  $driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps})
end
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's chrome-only.. do you know of an example for firefox?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out!!! Here is a working example for `gem "selenium-webdriver"`. Should work too for Capybara as well.

First line is if you want to run a custom binary. In case of --headless command line argument, support starts from firefox version 55. Don't forget to make firefox-nightly available to $PATH Env Var.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = "/home/user/bin/firefox-nightly"
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(
  "moz:firefoxOptions" => {
    args: ["--headless"] # and other arguments... 
  }
)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, desired_capabilities: caps
```

`# do stuff here ....
driver.quit`